# Should I use thread in my library?

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll

I am implementing a function in library which takes a while (up to a minute). It initialize a device. Now generally any long function should run in its own thread and report to main thread when it completes but I am not sure since this function is in library.

My dilemma is this, even if I implement this in a separate thread, another thread in the application has to wait on it. If so why not let the application run this function in that thread anyways?

I could pass queue or mailbox to the library function but I would prefer a simpler mechanism where the library can be used in VB, VC, C# or other windows platforms.

Alternatively I could pass HWND of the window and the library function can post message to it when it completes instead of signaling any event. That seems like most practical approach if I have to implement the function in its own thread. Is this reasonable?

Currently my function prototype is:

```
void InitDevice(HANDLE hWait)
```

When initialization is complete than I signal `bWait`. This works fine but I am not convinced I should use thread anyways when another *secondary thread* will have to wait on `InitDevice`. Should I pass `HWND`instead? That way the message will be posted to the *primary thread* and it will make better sense with multithreading.

Comment: Leave the threading to the user of your library if possible, IMO. They can then use whatever threading model they would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when I write library code, I normally try to stay away from creating threads unless it's really necessary.  By creating a thread, you're forcing a particular threading model on the application.  Perhaps they wish to use it from a very simplistic command-line tool where a single thread is fine.  Or they could use it from a GUI tool where things must be multi-threaded.

So, instead, just give the library user understanding that a function call is a long-term blocking call, some callback mechanism to monitor the progress, and finally a way to immediately halt the operation which *could* be used by a multi-threaded application.

What you *do* want to claim is being **thread safe**.  Use mutexes to protect data items if there are other functions they can call to affect the operation of the blocking function.

Comment: This make sense to me. The long wait (and thread) also made me think if I should send minor update messages to the client like `module 1 initialized, module 2 initialized` etc that goes into the realms of MVC and keeping it simple and thread safe seems to the best bet.